# Variable value Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
var vatDisplay = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tax-amount"));
Assert.AreEqual("£13.80", vatDisplay.Text);
```

I wanted to do this item in another way like rather than telling

```
Assert.AreEqual("£13.80", vatDisplay.Text);
```

I need to say if it is `vatDisplay.Text > £0.00` and I do not know how to do that.
Can Anyone please tell me how to do that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [parse the string value into a decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) and then verify that the resulting value is a positive number:

```
var vatDisplay = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tax-amount"));
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
decimal amount;
if (!decimal.TryParse(vatDisplay, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out amount))
{
    Assert.Fail(
        "{0} is an invalid currency and it cannot be verified that the amount is positive",  
        vatDisplay
    );
}
Assert.IsTrue(amount > 0);
```

Comment: In particular using `Decimal.Parse` overload that takes a `NumberStyles` option so you can pass `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`.

Comment: @Richard, yes that one in particular. Also `NumberStyles.Currency` should be used.